Let's get critical: Dec 2013 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

From Fourier Transforms to Option Values
Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)




Integration of stochastic total derivative
Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)




Is "Issuer and Holder with same strike" meaningless?
Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)




Fixed Income free research available online
Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)




SDE simulation: P or Q?
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)




Risk Neutral Probability
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)




Time Series or Regression
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)




Is Vasicek risk neutral?
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)




ADF test in R yielding perfect cointegration. How is this possible?
Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)




tail correlation during crisis
Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)




The boilerplate instructions said to discuss here, so I shall.
There are two questions that are not a good fit for this website, as they are too basic. However, the answers are decent, responding to the question and more. Please see 
Time Series or Regression  There were two, maybe three good answers, and I don't believe the question should be deleted, though maybe closed. OP did not ever select an answer, but rather, cited Wikipedia in a comment on one of the answers.
I shall return and append if I can relocate the other question.
